# Android Studio not reflecting my changes

Tags: android-studio

Currently my Andriod studio is stuck at point where whatever changes I make in Studio is not getting reflected in apk. I invalidated the cache and restarted Android studio still doest work. I restarted the machine still I am getting this.. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try to manually uninstall the apk ?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945517/not-getting-updated-apk-file-project-running-on-android-studio) and read comments too.

Comment: Delete apk from **build\outputs** in your project source then run the application.If you can find new apk check it or else you have some other problem in studio

Comment: I did manually uninstall the apk, did remove the apk from build output.. this didnt help.. Studio is not building the  apk properly

Comment: In my case it was an issue with Instant Run: Settings-> Build, Execution, Deployment->Instant Run and uncheck the "Enable Instant Run to..."