# I have updated data in my code but when i build apk file those content are not showing react native apk file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have updated a code in visual studio, it react native code. one folder android is present which I use to open in android studio to open and build apk file. but it is not updating the code, how can i build the android folder so that apk will be generated with updated code.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16946047/19330634) help you ?